# Use Jquery hide in a PHP array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a function to show addition info in my php array. I am echoing tables that show information for my classes and I cannot get the Jquery to work while inside the PHP. I'm not the most experienced in Jquery or PHP so I must be placing it completely wrong.

EDIT: I know my PHP queries are not safe, I have start converting those over eventually.
Here is my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bigcalendar.css">

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />

    <title>Webbook | View Schedule</title>

    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />

    <!--[if IE]>
      <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='js/dynamicpage.js'></script>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#hidetest").toggle(1000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="page-wrap">

        <header>
                 <?php include "navbar.php";?>

        </header>

        <section id="main-content">
        <div id="guts">

          <h2>View Schedule</h2>

<?php
//get database settings
include("dbinfo.php");

?>



<div align="center">
<?php
$sqlschedule = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE student='Austin' ORDER BY `hour`  ASC");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sqlschedule);
//Table starting tag and header cells
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlschedule)){
   //Display the results in different cells
   $hour = $row['hour'];
   $class = $row['class'];
   $teacher = $row['teacher'];
   $classid = $row['classid'];


$sqlclassid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM classes WHERE classid=$classid");
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sqlclassid)){
$hour2 = $row2['hour'];
$class2 = $row2['class'];
$teacher2 = $row2['teacher'];
}
if($class == ""){
$class = $class2;
}
if($teacher == ""){
$teacher = $teacher2;
}

$sqlhourinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hours WHERE hour='$hour'");
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($sqlhourinfo)){
$starttime = strftime("%l:%M %P", strtotime($row3['starttime']));
$endtime = strftime("%l:%M %P", strtotime($row3['endtime']));
}
/*
$from = mysql_query("SELECT * from members WHERE username='$fromuser'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($from);
//Table starting tag and header cells
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($from)){
   //Display the results in different cells
   $otherid = $row['id'];
   $theusername = $row['username'];
}
*/



echo '<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p style="display:none" id="hidetest">This is another small paragraph.</p>
<button>Toggle</button>
';
   echo '     
<table id="background-image" width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="10">
  <tr>
    <th width="10%" rowspan="2" class="scheduleform" scope="col">'.$hour.'</th>
    <td align="left" scope="col">'.$class.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left">'.$teacher.'</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><p>Starts: '.$starttime.'<br>
      Ends: '.$endtime.'
    </p></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="#" id="opener">
<img border="0" src="/webbook/images/256.png" alt="Add Assignment" width="32" height="32"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#">
<img border="0" src="/webbook/images/256 (1).png" alt="Edit Assignment" width="32" height="32"></a>
</td>

</tr>
</table>







      </p>

';

}

?>

      </div>

</div>
</div>


        </div>
        </section>

    </div>

    <footer>
      &copy;2013 iHeff Webbook
    </footer>
    <?php   /* 
include('../footer.php'); 
*/ ?>
</body>

</html>
```

So I want to achieve is there is a link with an image that says "add assignment". I want to be able to click that and then a hidden form shows up and you can toggle it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: use the php to generate all the html. display it to the page. once its on the page you can use the javascript on it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you think you could give me an example? I'm kind of confused as to what you mean by that.

Comment: Post the HTML and Javascript generated by php to jsfiddle so we can see what it's doing

Answer (score 0):

The id of your link is "opener", but you are using `('button').click(`... etc.

use `$('#opener').click` instead.  That should tie the click function to the link.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but right now that link isn't relative to the problem I'm having. Sorry, I made that confusing in my question. Right now I'm just trying to test it with the button and the <p id="hidetest"> Once I get that figured out I'll move it over to the link and change the tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply set `display:none` to your form container and register a click listener and use jquery .show() to pop up the form. Here's an example:

```
<a href="#" id="addassgn">Add Assignment</a>
<div id="assgnform" style="display:none">
    <h1>Assignment Form</h1>
    Name: <input type="text"/><br/>
    Class: <input type="text"/><br/>
    File: <input type="text"/><br/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</div>

$('#addassgn').click(function() {
    $('#assgnform').show();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vZreC/

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that won't work for me either. I click on the link and nothing happens.

Comment: I know it works as a standalone, but once I try putting it in my code, in the PHP part, it will not.